# Bash to combine two text files from separate folders in the same directory

Tags: bash

I am trying to use `bash` to combine the contents of two text files from different folders in the same directory.  The below does execute but produces the current output below. Hopefully it is close but I am not sure why it is not producing the desired output. Thank you :).

**bash**

```
topdir=/home/cmccabe/Desktop/s5.2
dir1=/home/cmccabe/Desktop/s5.2/Folder1
dir2=/home/cmccabe/Desktop/s5.2/Folder2
for f in $dir1/*.txt
do
$(basename "$f")
outf=$topdir/all.txt
cp $f $outf
sed -e '1 d' $dir2/*.txt >> $outf
done
```

**Description of directory layout:**

```
toplevel directory `/home/cmccabe/Desktop/s5.2`
   |
Folder1   Folder2 `/home/cmccabe/Desktop/s5.2/Folder1` or `/home/cmccabe/Desktop/s5.2/Folder2`
   |         |
 .txt      .txt   `$dir1.txt` or `$dir.txt`
```

**Contents of text file from dir1**

```
xxx_000 00-0000_La-Fi
xxx_001 00-0001_L-F
xxx_002 00-0002_xx-xxx
R_2017_SomeName

xx_0000 xxx
xx_0001 xxx1
xx_0002 xxx2
xx_0003 xxx3
R_2017_SomeName
```

**Contents from text file at dir2**

```
xxx_006 00-0000_La-Fi
xxx_007 00-0001_L-F
xxx_008 00-0002_xx-xxx
R_2017_SomeName
```

**current output**

```
file1.txt command not found in the terminal but `all.txt` is created and looks like:

xxx_000 00-0000_La-Fi
xxx_001 00-0001_L-F
xxx_002 00-0002_xx-xxx
R_2017_SomeName

xx_0000 xxx
xx_0001 xxx1
xx_0002 xxx2
xx_0003 xxx3
R_2017_SomeName  --- not carrying over the newline ---
xxx_007 00-0001_L-F
xxx_008 00-0002_xx-xxx
R_2017_SomeName
```

**desired result**

```
xxx_000 00-0000_La-Fi
xxx_001 00-0001_L-F
xxx_002 00-0002_xx-xxx
R_2017_SomeName

xx_0000 xxx
xx_0001 xxx1
xx_0002 xxx2
xx_0003 xxx3
R_2017_SomeName

xxx_006 00-0000_La-Fi
xxx_007 00-0001_L-F
xxx_008 00-0002_xx-xxx
R_2017_SomeName
```

Comment: Yes, only 1 text file with the same name will be present in each folder. Thank you :).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can perhaps make things simple by running a loop like below using brace expansion from the `/home/cmccabe/Desktop/s5.2/` as

```
outf="/home/cmccabe/Desktop/s5.2/final.txt"

for f in ./Folder{1,2}/*.txt; do 
    printf "%s\n" "$(< $f )" >> "$outf"
done
```

Comment: Any reason you like `printf "%s\n" "$(< $f )" >> "$outf"` instead of `cat "$f" >> "$outf"`? Are you using `printf` for the `newline` separation between the files? Maybe `cat ...; echo "" >> "$outf"`? Just curious.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin: Thanks for the insight! was cautious not to use any third party tools for this, especially `cat`. But how do you mean `"$f >> "$outf"` which might print only the file-name no?

Comment: I was thinking and typing at the same time -- dangerous. The no 3rd party tools was the key.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin: Happens all the time!

Comment: OP wants to skip the first line of the second file.

Answer (score 1):

You do not need the for-loop.

```
topdir=/home/cmccabe/Desktop/s5.2
dir1=/home/cmccabe/Desktop/s5.2/Folder1
dir2=/home/cmccabe/Desktop/s5.2/Folder2
outf=$topdir/all.txt
cp $dir1/*.txt $outf
# The question is not complete clear to me,
# the next echo can be deleted when you do not want an empty line
echo >> $outf
sed -e '1 d' $dir2/*.txt >> $outf
```

or

```
cat $dir1/*.txt <(echo) <(sed -e '1 d' $dir2/*.txt) > $outf
```